# How to sort Firebase Database children?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to select all nodes whose category is fashion, please suggest me a way, how to do it?

Here is code that I am trying, but it's not working:

```
databaseRef.child("All");
    databaseRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo("Fashion");
    databaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {...}
```

here is a JSON data.

```
{
  "-KZ23rvePtICBnQ_0eh-" : {
    "category" : "Fashion",
    "description" : "",
    "link" : "",
    "name" : "abof"
  },
  "-KZ2PgVpI-R60ZuFSnS2" : {
    "category" : "Fashion",
    "description" : " and answer",
    "link" : "fhhggh",
    "name" : "Amazon"
  },
  "-KZ2QayVvfZ6MN6V6Xhm" : {
    "category" : "Fashion",
    "description" : "get  50 % off on top brands",
    "link" : "wwe.abof.com",
    "name" : "abof"
  },
  "-KZ2Qj4XA2FWZm3V46TM" : {
    "category" : "Fashion",
    "description" : "",
    "link" : "www.myntra.com",
    "name" : "Myntra"
  },
  "-KZ2QrklT7cTCZMjmqZi" : {
    "category" : "Travels",
    "description" : "",
    "link" : "www.olacab.com",
    "name" : "Ola"
  },
  "-KZ2RZ5E5dt1GxRzuo37" : {
    "category" : "Travels",
    "description" : "get off on today's ride",
    "link" : "www.makemytrip.com",
    "name" : "MakeMyTrip"
  },
  "-KZ2RiM8fdYYa0e9yceR" : {
    "category" : "Travels",
    "description" : "free ride up to 50 km",
    "link" : "www.uber.com",
    "name" : "Uber"
  },
  "-KZ2S3kTGXfA014r7Bu1" : {
    "category" : "Food",
    "description" : "buy one get one free",
    "link" : "www.burgering.com",
    "name" : "Burgerking"
  },
  "-KZ2SL6DyCQ791kMO4jW" : {
    "category" : "Food",
    "description" : "flat 60% off only today",
    "link" : "www.kfc.com",
    "name" : "KFC"
  },
  "-KZ2SX3k5bq36alQ_V_c" : {
    "category" : "Recharge",
    "description" : "cash back offer",
    "link" : "www.paytm.com",
    "name" : "Paytm"
  },
  "-KZ2SfuH8x8Ifp1kh3cW" : {
    "category" : "Recharge",
    "description" : "get cash back",
    "link" : "www.mibokwik.com",
    "name" : "MoboKwik"
  },
  "-KZ2SvnogJ-iFYrkCzAu" : {
    "category" : "Mobiles",
    "description" : "get 20% off on order above 6000",
    "link" : "www.flipkart.com",
    "name" : "Flipkart"
  },
  "-KZ2T9XwueMaqN9hx65g" : {
    "category" : "Mobiles",
    "description" : "flat 20% off",
    "link" : "www.flipkart.com",
    "name" : "Amazon"
  },
  "-KZ2TTDrahu-XCaS7BkI" : {
    "category" : "Movies",
    "description" : "get off on today's show. ",
    "link" : "www.paytm.com",
    "name" : "Paytm"
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Ok sir, Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to chain those requests.  For example,

```
    databaseRef.child("All").orderByChild("category").equalTo("Fashion").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    }
```